# SQL query date today +7 (WEEK)

Tags: php, sql

I try load the data for this week. I have a column with the date the format "YYYYMMD".

Below you see my code but this shows nothing.

My question is: which SQL request can I made to load the data for this week

```
    function get_all_records($sql){
        global $conn;

        $query = $conn->query($sql);
        $result = [];
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) $result[array_shift($row)] = $row;
        return $result;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT day, starttime, endtime, date, scheduleType FROM schedule WHERE scheduleType = ";
    $shop_hours = array_merge(
        get_all_records($sql . "1 BETWEEN NOW() and mod(date + 7 - " . date('N') . ",7)"),
    );
```

hope somebody can help me

Comment: "I have a column with the date the format "YYYYMMD"" -- does that mean the columns data type is `varchar` or `char`? If it is first thing you should changing a proper date/time datatype for it.

Comment: No the datatype is date but the column has the name date also